# How to see new entries without refreshing the page?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

In my `page.html` using ngIf, data is fetched from local storage using below code:

```
<!--
  Generated template for the EducationPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    <ion-title>Education</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="newentry.title" type="text" placeholder="Title" [value]="title ? title: ''">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="newentry.description" type="text" placeholder="Description">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="newentry.tagline" type="text" placeholder="Tag line">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="newentry.date" type="text" placeholder="Date">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button item-right>
       <ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="save(newentry);"></ion-icon>
      <!--  <ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="editmode ? save() : editedu(elem, index)"></ion-icon> -->
      </button>
  <ul id="elements">
    <li *ngFor="let elem of fetchdata; let index = index">
      {{elem.title}} {{elem.description}}
      <button ion-button item-right (click)="editedu(elem,index);">
                <ion-icon name="open"></ion-icon>
              </button>
      <button ion-button item-right (click)="deleteedu(elem,index)">
                  <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>                 
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>

</ion-content>
```

On this same page I have a form to add new data, but when I add and save, I have to load the page from menu again to see the new data entered, how can this load instantly ?

This is how my page looks:

[image]

### Update

Posting my `page.ts` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Education } from "./education";

/**
 * Generated class for the EducationPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
//@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-education',
  templateUrl: 'education.html',
})




export class EducationPage {

  list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
  //myArray =  [{title:"saurabh" , description:"dd" , tagline:"tt", date:"dd"},{title:"gaurav" , description:"dd" , tagline:"tt", date:"dd"}];
  myArray = [];
  number1 = 5;
  newentry = { title: "", description: "", tagline: "", date: "", id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10) };
  data = '';
  fetchdata = [];
  dataObj: Education[] = [];
  elem = '';
  index;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EducationPage');
    //console.log(this.list);
    // console.log(this.myArray);
    //  localStorage.setItem("education-number",JSON.stringify(this.list));
    this.data = localStorage.getItem('education');
    if (!this.data) {
      localStorage.setItem("education", JSON.stringify(this.myArray));
    }
    this.fetchdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('education'));
    console.log(this.fetchdata);

  }

  // updateeditmode(){
  //   this.editmode=true;
  //   console.log(this.editmode);
  // }

  editedu(elem, index) {
    // console.log(elem); 
    console.log("inside editedu::");
    this.newentry = elem;
    this.newentry.title = elem.title;
    // this.fetchdata.splice(index, 1);
    //elem.title = 'CLICKED';
    console.log(this.fetchdata);
    localStorage.setItem("education", JSON.stringify(this.fetchdata));
  }

  deleteedu(elem, index) {
    console.log(elem);
    console.log(index);
    this.fetchdata.splice(index, 1);
    //elem.title = 'CLICKED';
    console.log(this.fetchdata);
    localStorage.setItem("education", JSON.stringify(this.fetchdata));
  }



  save(entry: Education) {
    this.data = localStorage.getItem('education');
    console.log("save working");
    console.log(this.data);
    if (this.data) //check if it exists or not empty
    {
      console.log("inside save function");
      this.dataObj = JSON.parse(this.data); //parse string
      console.log(this.dataObj);   
      let filtered = this.dataObj.filter(t => t.id === entry.id);
      if (filtered.length > 0) {
        this.dataObj[this.dataObj.findIndex(eel=>eel.id === entry.id)] = entry;
      } else {
        this.dataObj.push(this.newentry);
      }
      console.log(this.dataObj);
      localStorage.setItem("education", JSON.stringify(this.dataObj));
    }



    console.log("inside save edit area");
    //this.editedu(this.elem,this.index);
  }

}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: html or ts file ?

Comment: "below code" doesn't show anything about localStorage.What is `fetchdata`?

Comment: You have to add the data to your table, which is `fetchdata`. Since you get the data from the local storage, you should use `NgZone` to run your non-Angular code.

Comment: All the code that is needed so that we can understand how you're currently adding a new item.

Comment: updated my question, posted entire .ts code

Comment: call this function ionViewDidLoad() method once you save data

Comment: Your HTML page displays the elements in fetchdata. Your save method doesn't add anything to fetchdata. So why would the displayed items change. Hint: TypeScript has local variables. Almost all the fields declared in your component should be local variables. The fields should contain the state of your component, that is used by the template. Not all the local variables needed by your various methods.

Comment: worked by calling this.ionViewDidLoad(); in the end of save function

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

> ApplicationRef.tick() - similar to Angular 1's $rootScope.$digest() --
>   i.e., check the full component tree
>
> ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() - similar to $scope.$digest() --
>   i.e., check only this component and its children

After you get you update your data from subscribe method, use one of these to update the view with new changes.